# ImageView onClick listener in headerLayout not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fading

I have inflated a view in fragment like this: using([FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar))

```
@Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
   super.onAttach(activity);
    mFadingHelper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
        .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background_light)
        .headerLayout(R.layout.trailer_header)
        .contentLayout(R.layout.fragment_movie_detail_tab)
        .lightActionBar(true);
      mFadingHelper.initActionBar(activity);
  }
```

How do i able to implement the clickListener on header layout or any other views in header?

Comment: did u try using layout inflater? Inflate the header layout and find the view using findViewByid for setting onclicklistener.

Comment: You have used this library before. actually it won't let us inflate header separately. after that onattch we can access this way. view = mFadingHelper.createView(inflater); but when i do view.findViewById. it isn't working

Comment: No, I havent used it before.
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trailer_header, null);
ImageView img = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.image_view); try this....